# How to run python from different drive using Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

My OS is Windows 10.

I have test.py file in E drive.

I installed Python 3.7.2 and Visual Studio Code in C drive.

I set system path for Python 3.7.2 so I could run python on CMD on both of the drives.

[image]

I also set python.pythonPath in setting.json file in .vscode under my work folder.

So python.pythonPath is same as the system path.

but I can't run that test.py file on VScode.

It shows python 3.7.2 file's path and says "No such file or directory".

Is there a way to run python file on different drive using VScode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use debugging to run specific files in a reusable way.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging

It will create a launch.json file with contents similar to this. You can add additional
properties. VSCode is good about helping you create and edit the launch.json file.

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "RunPython",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            // run a file by specifying a full path
            "program": "E:/FullPathTo/FileA.py",
            // OR run the file currently open in VSCode
            // // "program": "${file}",
            // OR run a file relative to the current folder you have open
            // // "program": "${workspaceFolder}/folder/FileB.py"
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "args": ['InputArg1','InputArg2']
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've already set Python as an environment variable, you can simply route to the directory where the file is present (in this case E: drive) and run the command:

```
python test.py
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed Code Runner Extension and it followed my system path of python 3.7.2 automatically.
Now I can simply run my code with this short cut "Crtl+Alt+N" instead of entering "python test.py" every time on the terminal.